# changing property contentsGravity in transform-only layer, will have no effect

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9, xcode7, uistackview

I started to create a very simple tic-tac-toe game.
The main goal is to make the view proportional to all screen sizes of all iOS devices.
So I put the image on a `ViewController`, make it full size of screen and then I put it into a Stack View. I've added constrains to this Stack View 0 to all sides.
And when I ran the simulator then everything looks good. But I receive a message in console panel. What does it mean?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: please show your code :)

Comment: there are no code yet. It is a blank project with elements on Main Storyboard. Look at screenshot on the first message

Comment: This has appeared since using Xcode 7+. I believe other people view this as an "error" from something Apple has done and nothing you have done, but I can't confirm this. I've submitted apps with this and everything seems to be fine.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

It could happen because you changed the Mode attribute of the StackView:

[image]

I got this warning when I set Mode to Aspect Fit.

Comment: I set the mode back to Scale To Fill and the warning was gone. Thanks.

Comment: **How did you figure this out?** the warning doesn't show any indication of what is causing the problem. But after having this issue, your method solved the problem. I am still curious to know your method of figuring this out.

Comment: I think that simple's answer better explains the reason of the problem

Comment: bruteforce? accident? he is Mr Stacker :D

Comment: Thank you @Lubos Ilcik, it was exactly this problem for me. Cheers

Comment: This is still a thing in 2019 (Xcode 10.2.1)... *sigh*

Comment: Thanks, it save me tons of time to figure out the cause.

Comment: I'm building my UI programmatically and set the content mode to center. Removing that fixes the issue. What a frustrating error message.

Answer (score 75):

Any layer change on a `UIStackView` will result in this warning. As the warning points out `UIStackView` is a *transform-only layer* and it differs quite slightly from a `UIView`. As per documentation:

> The UIStackView is a nonrendering subclass of UIView; that is, it does
>   not provide any user interface of its own. Instead, it just manages
>   the position and size of its arranged views. As a result, some
>   properties (like backgroundColor) have no effect on the stack view.
>   Similarly, you cannot override layerClass, drawRect:, or
>   drawLayer:inContext:.

More on this [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/).

It may not point to the exact source of the OP's issue but hopefully, it will shed some light on why `UIStackView` behaviour is not the same and should not be confused with `UIView`.

Comment: I think this is by far the most precise answer

Comment: Thanks @allemattio

Comment: Thanks so much. I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure out why a UIView SUBCLASS doesn't react properly to drawRect override and layer manipulations... I think Apple should emphasize this about stack views way more in the docs.

Comment: Glad that I could help @jaga, agree with you on the emphasizing, there is no way to understand that when working with `UIStackView`s.

Comment: @victor.vasilica Let's say I'm creating a theme class to change colors globally within an app and I want all my `UIView`s to have a specified background color, should I do that work on the individual VC in `viewDidAppear` instead of trying to use UIAppearance?

Comment: @Adrian your new question doesn't relate to the topic of this thread. It depends, my opinion is that UIAppearance should be avoided. I recommend using protocols, subclasses or composition to achieve it. Using `viewDidAppear` is also an option but it defeats the purpose of a global theme class.

Comment: @victor.vasilica Thank you. I'm getting the exact same error the OP encountered. I commented out the code I was using for `UIView` and it went away...and my `UIViews` that were generating the error were inside `UIStackViews`, though they render the color as desired. Concur re: `viewDidAppear`. I'm trying to do something that's "one stop shopping" without a bunch of book keeping on the individual VCs. I'll try your suggestion. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

For someone that need: I set `clipToBounds` to false in StackView.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like what you did is perfectly correct.

However, I'm wondering why you chose to put your imageview into a stackview when you could have just as easily pinned the sides without the stackview.  I am a big fan of stackviews but they don't make sense everywhere.  Unless you're planning on adding new views, and resizing your ticktactoe board, I might not use it.

Comment: Well I can see that sometimes it would be nice to have stuff in stack views so you could change the orientation as needed without worrying about constraints and/or having two different classes to handle just two different orientations

Comment: I sometimes question myself for the use of StackView over pinning the views.  I found that StackView is better choice for several reasons: #1 adding or removing elements will not break anything, #2 client (or designer) keep changing things, colleagues (or future me) won't have to worry about #1 when #2 happens