# CATransformLayer : changing property masksToBounds in transform-only layer, will have no effect

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm using Xcode 7 and swift 2.

On my iPad Air, iOS 9.1, when the keyboard appear, an error is throw on the debug console

```
2015-10-28 13:07:35.114 Note[73896:6954126] <CATransformLayer: 0x7a2dc070> - changing property masksToBounds in transform-only layer, will have no effect
2015-10-28 13:07:35.115 Note[73896:6954126] <CATransformLayer: 0x7a2dd090> - changing property masksToBounds in transform-only layer, will have no effect
2015-10-28 13:07:35.115 Note[73896:6954126] <CATransformLayer: 0x7a035df0> - changing property masksToBounds in transform-only layer, will have no effect
```

Is it a bug from Apple ?

**EDIT :**

It seems to be a bug from Applen anyone had resolved it alone ?

Comment: Check the solutions provided for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33185720/changing-property-contentsgravity-in-transform-only-layer-will-have-no-effect

Answer (score 7):

not sure if this will work for you but appears that error comes from playing with the mode setting in IB on a UIStackView (scale to fill, aspect fit etc) changing it to aspect fit returns this error as well as checking clip to subviews.

Hope That Helps!