# iOS : warning: changing property masksToBounds in transform-only layer, will have no effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I already go though
[<CATransformLayer: 0x14fea3710> - changing property masksToBounds in transform-only layer, will have no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32775575/catransformlayer-0x14fea3710-changing-property-maskstobounds-in-transform-o)
["changing property masksToBounds in transform-only layer, will have no effect" in Xcode 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32456727/changing-property-maskstobounds-in-transform-only-layer-will-have-no-effect-i)
[CATransformLayer : changing property masksToBounds in transform-only layer, will have no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33392562/catransformlayer-changing-property-maskstobounds-in-transform-only-layer-will)

but still confused about this warning
i get this warning on

```
 [self presentViewController:alertViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

here i am adding UIAlertViewController in ViewController
1. how can i remove this warning.
2. should i ignore it.
or there is some other way to show UIAlertViewController in viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

Its a known issue in iOS comes in various scenarios like:

1. Presenting Custom Keyboard
2. Presenting `UIActivityViewController`
   etc.

So you simply need to ignore it